# How to understand sns.distplot chart using fmri data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm creating a visualization for the fmri sample dataset in the seaborn library. I used this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.displot(
    data=fmri,
    x="timepoint", y="signal",hue="region",
    kind="kde", height=9,
    multiple="fill", clip=(-25.0, None),
    palette="ch:rot=-.25,hue=1,light=.75",

)
```

This gave me an output using this chart:
[image: graph]

My problem is that I don't understand this chart format or even what it's called to look up more information on it. What do the circles mean? Is this an effective way to display this type of data? I really like how it looks and I want to narrate what this means but would love to have some insight if anyone could help me understand a bit more.

Thanks!

Comment: Also have a look at the [wikipedia article about contour lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sns.distplot` is depreciated as you can find out more information here: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html

So, your best choice is `sns.kdeplot()`.

In your example you can do:

```
sns.kdeplot(data=fmri, bw_adjust = 0.2, fill = True)
```

The circles you are referring to are contours and shows the density at different manifolds.

I believe signal and timepoint are two variables and so the contours show the highest density around the smaller circles. If you use `fill = True` you may have a better vision of how the density is changing around each contour.

Comment: The fill function helped to understand the visualization much better, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complex question, as plots depend on the data type, story, you want to tell with your answers, questions you want to answer.
fMRI measures metabolism in different parts of the brain. The plot you've created tells us, that signal is similar in frontal and parietal lob in terms of the power of the signal and throughout observational time.
So it answers a certain question, that the observed signal was similar in both lobes.
This type of plots (contour plots) is valuable when representing multivariable data - to show a relationship between two variables (time and signal power/amplitude in this particular case).